# Java: Casting to Generic with Interface Pointers

Tags: java, generics, casting

In the following sample code two classes `EventA` and `EventB` both implement the `interface Historical`.  Java can automatically cast an `EventA` or `EventB` to `Historical` when one of these objects is passed as a parameter, as in the `examineEvent` method below.  However, Java is no longer able to cast when a generic is introduced ie. from `List<EventA>` to `List<Historical>` -- Unless the target function (in this case `findClosestValidEventIndex`) is declared using `List<? extends Historical>`.

Can someone explain why this must be? It seems to me that the very use of an interface in a generic should automatically imply the `<? extends Interface>`.

```
public class SampleApplication {

   public interface Historical {
      public DateTime getDate();
   }   

   public static class EventA implements Historical {
      private DateTime date;
      @Override
      public DateTime getDate() {
         return date;
      }
   }

   public static class EventB implements Historical {
      private DateTime date;
      @Override
      public DateTime getDate() {
         return date;
      }
   } 

   private static int findClosestValidEventIndex(List<Historical> history, DateTime when) {
      // do some processing
      return i;
   }

   private static int examineEvent(Historical event){
      return j;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      DateTime target = new DateTime();
      // AOK
      EventA a = new EventA(target);
      int idy = examineEvent(a);
      // Type Error --- Unless 
      List<EventA> alist = new ArrayList<EventA>();
      int idx = findClosestValidEventIndex(alist, target);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `List<EventA>` is *not* `List<Historical>`. Imagine:

```
List<EventA> list = ...;
List<Historical> h = (List<Historical>) list;
h.add(new EventB()); //type-safety of list is compromised
for (EventA evt : list) { // ClassCastException - there's an EventB in the lsit
   ...
}
```

`List<? extends Historical>` means "a list of a one specific subtype of Historical", and you cannot add anything to it, because at compile time you don't know what the type is.

Answer (score 3):

It can't always use `extends`, because sometimes you may need different behaviour.

Covariance (`extends`) is needed when generic object is used as a *producer*. When generic object is used as a *consumer*, you need contravariance (`super`). Practical rule is "**producer - extends, consumer - super**":

```
public void getEventFromHistory(List<? extnds Historical> history) {
    Historical e = history.get(0); // history is a producer of e
}

public void addEventAToHistory(List<? super EventA> history) {
    history.add(new EventA()); // history is a consumer
}

// Possible usage
List<EventA> sequenceOfEventsA = ...;
addEventAToHistory(sequenceOfEventsA);

List<Historical> history = ...;
addEventToHistory(history);
```

Comment: The rule you present sounds useful but I am not sure I understand the need for `? super`.  Is this basically declaring a weakly typed Object pointer?  Are you still able to use the super class's methods when accessing a generic method of this type?

Comment: @Colin: Didn't get your comment. Perhaps updated code sample makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass in a a collection bound to a subclass to a method argument which is bound to a collection of super class.

It's because the declaration List history by definition means that it is a list that is capable of holding anything that extends Historical. Which means you can add either EventA or EventB or a mix of those types into this collection.

But List<EventA> means a list which can support only objects of type EventA or a subtype of that. Such a list cannot contain EventB added into it.

Therefore, Java doesn't allow you to pass a List<EventA> as a valid argument to a method parameter which expects a List<Historical>. After all, though there is a inheritance relationship between Historical and EventA and Historical and EventB, there's no such relationship between a List<Historical> and a List<EventA>.