# Java - Cast ArrayList Up Hierarchy

Tags: java, casting, polymorphism

I have a simple class structure:

`class BaseModel {}`

`class Performer extends BaseModel {}`

And I have a collection of `Performer`s:

`ArrayList<Performer> list = loadPerformerList();`

Why can't I do this?

`functionThatNeedsArrayOfBase( (ArrayList<BaseModel>)list );`

Or, how can I do that, properly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A collection of child *is not* a collection of base.  Otherwise you could add base objects to your child collection, breaking the assumption (same the other way around as well).

You could specify the parameter to your function as a list containing derivatives of base:

```
void functionThatNeedsArrayOfBase(ArrayList<? extends BaseModel> list) {
  //...
}
```

Then you can just pass `list` without casting

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead: `<? extends BaseModel>`, it doesn't say which subclass of BaseModel just that it is one specific. See also `<? super BaseModel>`depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

list is an `ArrayList` of Performer(s).
If java allowed you to cast that to `ArrayList<BaseModel>`, even the list at that moment only contained BaseModel(s) what would happen when one adds an Performer to the list that is not a BaseModel? We lose type safety if we allow that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the type safety of the ArrayList.  You can find several more detailed explanations on this [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179638/java-casting-to-generic-with-interface-pointers).  In short, the way around this problem is to have the method accept classes of type `<? extends/super Performer>`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this does not work, is that it would allow `functionThatNeedsAnArrayOfBase()` to add a different BaseModel subclass to the list and corrupt the original list reference.

A good example with further explanation is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690684/java-cast-from-listb-to-lista-where-b-extends-a) stack overflow question.

Another good reference is Josh Bloch's coverage of Generics in Essential Java.